# ng-repeat in label and input value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have very large form field and in last step I would like to create a summary so people can see what they wrote there. It wouldn't be a problem to do this only with values which users passed to inputs but I also want to show labels of inputs before value.

So when HTML in form is:

```
<label for="one">First one:</label>
<input id="one" type="text" ng-model="firstInput">
```

I want to have something like:

> First one: firstInput.value

where `firstInput.value` is just text which user wrote in input.

I've created basic schema for this: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hI8LxzoGzUe70kqqDZeT?p=preview)

I do not have even idea how to accomplish that so I ask you for help.

**EDIT**

Actually as CanFil mentioned I can use `(key, value)` inside `ng-repeat` but it will display the `ng-model` name which in my case sometimes is meaningless for user that's why I prefer labels.

Comment: Just don't use an ng-repeat. Just like you have three inputs, use three `li`s.

Comment: Or also generate the inputs using a loop, but that will obviously force you to have an array of labels.

Comment: But number of inputs depends on what user chose during completing form. There may be 30 inputs or 50 depending what user selected.

Comment: If you're able to know which inputs to display based on the user input, you can apply the exact same logic to determine what to display in the summary.

Comment: You're right but it's eventuality solution because in this case you have to do a lot of work manually. However I will use it if nobody provide some better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat json as key-value pair like;

```
(key, value) in inputs
```

your inputs json should be empty and you should bind your html inputs like;

```
inputs.firstinput
```

and of course use {{value}} for showing the value

[Edited Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7nHjnrFbINhnDyOSItw1?p=preview)

Comment: I upvoted but in edit I explained why this solution is not perfect for me.

Comment: Ok. I updated plunker. It is a tricky but works. The point is your model name and id of input should be the same